# Installing App on Mac results in "is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the Bin."

Tags: macos, installation, gravio

When I try to drag the application file into my application folder, macOS gives me the error that says that the application was damaged and can't be opened and that I should move it to the trash.

Specifically I am doing this here with the [Gravio](https://www.gravio.com) HubKit App.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Gravio, this is likely to mean one of two things:

- that there are still some files in /usr/local/bin/Gravio* which were not removed properly during the last uninstall
- that there is already a folder in /usr/local/bin/Gravio* from a previous installation

You can fix it by backing up the Gravio related files in this folder:

```
sudo open /usr/local/bin/
```

Copy the files to a safe folder.

And then remove the files using the command

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/Gravio*
```

Then perform the installation again.